# Python 3 regex: spliting sentences not working properly

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp

I have the following text:

> 'The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring. Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2. It will change your view of the matrix. Are the human people the ones who started the war? Is AI a bad thing?'

And I'm trying to split it into sentences using the following regex:

```
re.split(r'[\.\?\!][\s\n]', text.strip())
```

For some reason it is not deleting the last question mark. The result I get is the following:

> ['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring',
>    'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2',
>    'It will change your view of the matrix',
>    'Are the human people the ones who started the war',
>    'Is AI a bad thing?']

I tried modifying a little bit the regex adding a "*" at the end:

```
re.split(r'[\.\?\!][\s\n]*', text.strip())
```

But this is what I get:

> ['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring',
>    'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2',
>    'It will change your view of the matrix',
>    'Are the human people the ones who started the war',
>    'Is AI a bad thing',
>    '']<------- See this empty string

How should I go about this? I cannot use NLTK here, I am required to use only python 3 regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the `split()` function's nature which devide a string into two by `separator`(or `delimiter`). When separator is appeared at the starting(or ending) position of the string, this pecular behavior which create an empty string by-product of processing of splitting may occurr.

To avoid or remove empty strings of this type, you may use another functions: `filter()` function to remove empty strings, or `re.match()` and `re.findall()` , etc.. like follows to avoide empty string elements from splitting.

a regex for the seperator

```
[\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)
```

- Using `filter()` function to remove empty string elements from splitting, or using `re.findall()` function to capture strings except `separator`.

```
ss="""The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring. Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2. It will change your view of the matrix. Are the human people the ones who started the war? Is AI a bad thing?"""

splt= re.split(r"[\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)",ss)
splt=list(filter(None,splt))
print(splt)


regs= re.compile(r'((?:(?![\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)).)*)[\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)')
match= regs.findall(ss)
print(match)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/36) for capturing regex which used in the `findall()`

```
((?:(?![\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)).)*)[\.\?\!](?:[\s]+|$)
```

script execution result is

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing']
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing']
```

Comment: I’m happy to hear that you are having fun with it, thank you:-)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the last element as blank because your regex `[\.\?\!][\s\n]*` matches the last `?` due to which split operation is performed on that `?` which gives you 2 strings - one present to the left of that `?` and one present at the right. The string present at the right of the last `?` is a blank string, hence you get the last element of the array blank.

Instead of splitting, you can get the matches by using the following regex:

```
[^.?!]+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQ09zZ/3)**

**[See the Python Code output here](http://rextester.com/TUWEF25030)**

Comment: I tried this regex and it doesn't work. It returns the second result I posted in my question, the last sentence is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. That regex matches the characters I wish to delete.